# How does one work on two unlocked packages at once?

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

Say for example I have broken my metadata up by having one package for standard objects, a number of packages for functional groupings of custom objects and a package for apex classes.

I'm not clear on how I can manage my project folder when I do some customisation for a build that includes modification of a standard object, addition of a new custom object and an update to an existing apex class.

Do I use three folders like ..\force-app\main\package1, ..\force-app\main\package2 and ..\force-app\main\package3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally recommended to use a directory for a package in the project workspace. So you are right that your project will have a folder structure as you have mentioned.

You do not need to use force-app, feel free to use the folder name that is more meaningful.

Example project workspace directory names as below

```
recruiting-module-baseobjects/main/default

recruiting-module-basecode/main/default
```

It is also recommended you enable [source tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm) on your sandboxes or use scratch orgs. That way it is easier to use commands like `force:source:pull` that automatically pulls into respective folders as long as you have a project directory path defined in `sfdx-project.json`

Take a peek into one of the sample apps [Easy-Spaces](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc) repo and see how we compose the app into modules or packages and map to the directory in the `sfdx-project.json` and also configure [dependencies](https://github.com/trailheadapps/easy-spaces-lwc/blob/develop/sfdx-project.json).

Also, one thing to note is not every metadata is supported for unlocked packaging so it is better to not put them in the package but still have a folder (`unpackaged` name fits well) where you can group them and deploy them using `force:source:deploy` or `force:mdapi:deploy` after/before you install the packages.

When you finally are done with the development you create package and package versions using the Salesforce command-line tool (CLI) by providing the package directory and package name.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent answer and the enable source tracking tip is very valuable.

The key understanding I was missing is the proper use of folders and mapping them to the packages in sfdx-project.json.